# date() function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, date

Whats the correct format using the date() function in PHP to insert into a MySQL date type column? or am I using the wrong function? I need to be able to insert the current date into the database via a mysql_query.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking (test1,test2,test3,Date_Booked) VALUES ('". $var1. ",". $var2.",". $var3 .","date()"')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `Date_Booked` column is expecting a `date` value it would be `date('Y-m-d')`. A better alternative might be to use MySQL's own date functionality. Using [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) or [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) would also accomplish the same thing:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking (test1,test2,test3,Date_Booked) 
    VALUES ('". $var1. ",". $var2.",". $var3 .",NOW())");

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking (test1,test2,test3,Date_Booked) 
    VALUES ('". $var1. ",". $var2.",". $var3 .",CURDATE())");
```

Answer (score 1):

My code, I use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` for a field of type "DATETIME" but this will depend on the data structure of your table.  There are other date string that may work depending.  Can you provide the structure of the date field in your table so I can revise my answer if needed?

Answer (score 0):

$insert = 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO

booking (test1,test2,test3,Date_Booked)

VALUES

('$var1','$var2','$var3','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");